# Data modeling in mongoDB - Social-media app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build some sort of a social media app using node.js and mongoDB.
I have a mongoose schema for 'User', and when i render some user page on the app, it needs to also show all of his posts/images/list of friends and etc...

right now i have a mongoose schema for 'UserPost' and also for 'Image', and when i save an image for example, it has a field which keeps the username of the user who uploaded it, so when i render the user page it finds all of his images.

It is the first time i'm dealing with db's so i heard that i might have to use a reference data instead of embedded data.

can someone explain to how should i organize the data model for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very handful to use mongoose population for handling db references

Define your schemas like these:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var userSchema = Schema({
  name    : String,
  posts : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});

var postSchema = Schema({
  title    : String,
  images   : [{ url: String, filename: String }]
});

var User  = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

According to mongoose [population docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), you can get all your data:

```
User.findOne().populate('posts').exec(function(error, user) {
  console.log(user.posts) // there are populated posts objects inside array
})
```

Not sure, is it a good idea to use separated collection for image uploads, it's simpier to embed it inside Post (or User), but you may always add `{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image' }` for images

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a NoSql DBMS. It means, you schould not create references between data fields, because the performance coming from NoSql will be killed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

But, if you are really thinking you need references, checkout this: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/database-references/

You can reference to a data document in the mongoDB by the _id ("Page"=>"createdBy" = "User"=>"_id" for example).

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what kind of data you want to embed. MongoDB has object size limits according to the storage engine you use. Thus you should predict or estimate the the size of the object you want to embed. 
See more about limits here: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/limits/ 
See more about references here: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/database-references/

Comment: I just don't want to make multiple queries in order to update some documents- for example: i want to update some username field, and this will force me to also update all of the user's posts, so i want the posts to be related to the user in a reference so i will not have to update them also.